# perl, having weird behavior with s///

Tags: perl

I'm embarrassed to ask this because it is so simple, but I can't see what's wrong. I have a routine to clean up input for an ip range. It's sort of brute-force but I don't know of a better way. The problem I am having is when I try to remove inner spaces leaving only a '-' or ',' as separators within a conditional block a single preceding and trailing space is left bracketing the separator. If I clean up the inner spaces outside the conditional block the spaces are properly removed. So, in the sample code if I only have the s/\s+//g on Line 1 it cleans properly, if I only have the s/\s+//g on Lines 2 and 3 spaces are left bracketing the '-' and ','. What the heck is wrong?

```
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

$input = "   192.168.1.1       198.168.1.254     ";
buildIpRangeArray ($input);

$input = "   192.168.1.1  ,     198.168.1.254     ";
buildIpRangeArray ($input);

$input = "   192.168.1.1    -  198.168.1.254     ";
buildIpRangeArray ($input);

sub buildIpRangeArray {

    say "input: $input";

    $input = shift;
    $input =~ s/^\s+//;
    $input =~ s/\s+$//;
#    $input =~ s/\s+//g;                    # Line 1. 
                                            # Works if this is uncommented
                                            # and lines 2 and 3 are omitted

    if ( index($input,' ') >= 0) {
        $input =~ s/\s+/ /g;                # this works
        say "cleaned input 2: $input";
        @range = split(/ /,$input);
        say Dumper(@range);
    }
    elsif ( index($input,',') >= 0) {
        $input =~ s/\s+//g;                 # Line 2
        say "cleaned input 3: $input";
        @range = split(/,/, $input);
        say Dumper(@range);
    }
    elsif ( index($input,'-') >= 0) {
        $input =~ s/\s+//g;                 # Line 3
        say "cleaned input 4: $input";
        @range = split(/-/, $input);
        say Dumper(@range);
    }
}
The output:
input:    192.168.1.1       198.168.1.254     
cleaned input 2: 192.168.1.1 198.168.1.254
$VAR1 = '192.168.1.1';
$VAR2 = '198.168.1.254';

input:    192.168.1.1  ,     198.168.1.254     
cleaned input 2: 192.168.1.1 , 198.168.1.254
$VAR1 = '192.168.1.1';
$VAR2 = ',';
$VAR3 = '198.168.1.254';

input:    192.168.1.1    -  198.168.1.254     
cleaned input 2: 192.168.1.1 - 198.168.1.254
$VAR1 = '192.168.1.1';
$VAR2 = '-';
$VAR3 = '198.168.1.254';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your debug output, it's fairly obvious what's going on. Let's take the second block of output with the comma.

> ```
> input:    192.168.1.1  ,     198.168.1.254     
> cleaned input 2: 192.168.1.1 , 198.168.1.254
> $VAR1 = '192.168.1.1';
> $VAR2 = ',';
> $VAR3 = '198.168.1.254';
> ```

After *input*, there is a check to see if there's a space `' '` in the string. There is, here:

```
           V
192.168.1.1 , 198.168.1.254
```

Therefore the code never reaches the `elsif` for the comma `,` or the dash `-`. You can verify that because you always get *input 2*, never *input 3* or *input 4*.

The next step is cleaning whitespace, where you say yourself it works. You replace lots of any whitespace with one space. That leaves `,` in the string. Now you split on whitespace, giving you

```
ip
,
ip
```

---

Overall, your code is fairly naive. There is a lot of repetition, and you don't have `use strict` or `use warnings`, which makes it harder to debug. Depending on how this code is going to be used, I suggest a huge simplification.

```
sub buildIpRangeArray {
    my $input = shift;

    say "input: $input";

    my @range = grep {$_} split /[^0-9.]+/, $input;
    say Dumper @range;
    return;
}
```

We split on lots of characters that can't be in an IP address. This is naive too, as it will not verify you have actual IP addresses, but neither does your code. It will work for any number of whitespace or any delimiters, even if they are text. We need the [`grep`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to remove empty strings that occur from leading or trailing whitespace. An empty string `""` in Perl evaluates as *false*, so `grep` will filter these out.

Comment: I thank you. I omitted parts that I didn't think relevant. I am very new to Perl, I know most of my solutions lack finesse. I'm working on it.

Comment: I will say that the grep preceding the split is confusing the heck out of me. Makes my head hurt

Comment: @Coltrane58 no worries, we've all started at some point. Please do not leave things out if you show people code to help you debug. That's like telling a mechanic your car is not starting but only bringing the keys. You'll learn in time which things are relevant and which aren't. You can always produce a [mcve] to show the problem, as long as it still occurs.

Comment: @Coltrane58 re the `grep`, it takes a block and a list, and throws away every list element where the block does not evaluate to true. It's a filter. A bit like `map` or `reduce` (in, JavaScript for example), just that it filters the list down rather than applying stuff to every element, or turning them all into a single value. The topic `$_` is the current value. All we do is check if it contains something that evaluates to true. False in Perl is `0`, `""` (empty string), `()` (empty list) and `undef`. Everything else is true.

Comment: So what value is $_ in the grep brackets? I was only familiar with grep with braces. Thanks much for the help and the pointers. Stackoverflow is great, I keep learning things. will take your advice regarding posting complete code.

Comment: @Coltrane58 the `grep` is like a `foreach` loop. It iterates over every element of the list, assigns it to `$_` and evaluates the block against it. A lot of Perl built-ins default to the value of `$_`. Examples you've probably seen are `chomp;` or `print;` with no arguments. They use `$_` _implicitly_ (that means without you saying so). In that `grep` block, we simply put `$_`, so that is everything that gets evaluated. `grep` takes the result (i.e. the return value) of the block and checks if it's true or false... 1/2

Comment: ... `my @filtered = grep { $_ }, ("foo", "", "bar")` the `$_` will be `"foo"`, `""`, `"bar"`. `"foo"` is a true value, `"bar"` is a true value, but the empty string `""` is false, so the result will be `"foo", "bar"`.

Comment: I remember when I first learned c++ and would have obfuscation contests. I think perl can be like hieroglyphs. Thanks again.

Comment: @Coltrane58 it certainly can be, but it doesn't have to be. Most code you read on CPAN today is really clear, well structured and very easy to read. That is a great way to learn more about the language, btw. Keep in mind that all the modules are just Perl code too, and you can look at all of them. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your first condition is always true, as the string always contains spaces.

So you have to write the if/elsif/elsif in another way.

```
if ( index($input,',') >= 0) {
    $input =~ s/\s+//g;                 # Line 2
    say "cleaned input 3: $input";
    @range = split(/,/, $input);
    say Dumper(@range);
}
elsif ( index($input,'-') >= 0) {
    $input =~ s/\s+//g;                 # Line 3
    say "cleaned input 4: $input";
    @range = split(/-/, $input);
    say Dumper(@range);
}
elsif ( index($input,' ') >= 0) {
    $input =~ s/\s+/ /g;                # this works
    say "cleaned input 2: $input";
    @range = split(/ /,$input);
    say Dumper(@range);
}
```

will probably yield the result you want.